# How to add a shape alternate in Orchard that is located in a subfolder?

Tags: orchardcms, shapes, alternate

I have a `IShapeTableProvider` that looks like this

```
public class ShapeProvider: Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.IShapeTableProvider
{
  public void Discover(Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTableBuilder aBuilder)
  {
    aBuilder.Describe("Parts_Container_Contained").OnDisplaying(c => OnShapeDisplaying(c));
  }

  private void OnShapeDisplaying(Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.ShapeDisplayingContext aDisplayingContext)
  {
    ...
    aDisplayingContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("Foo_Bar");
  }
}
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes#FromTemplateFileNametoShapeName) the alternate shape name `Foo_Bar` is mapped to `Foo\Bar` but `Bar` is never rendered. The default shape is used instead.

Is it even possible to discover shape alternates in subfolders?

**Edit**

When i renamed the `Parts.Container.Contained.cshtml` as requested by `devqon` i get the following exception

> Exception Details: Orchard.OrchardException: Formtyp
>   Parts_Container_Contained nicht gefunden

Source Error:

> Line 101: throw new OrchardException(T("Shape type {0} not found",
>   shapeMetadata.Type));

Source File:

> c:\Project\Web\Intranet.NET\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs
>   Line: 101

Stack Trace:

```
[OrchardException: Formtyp Parts_Container_Contained nicht gefunden]
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in c:\Project\Web\Intranet.NET\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:101
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in c:\Project\Web\Intranet.NET\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.Invoke(String name, INamedEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Project\Web\Intranet.NET\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:44
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in c:\Project\Web\Intranet.NET\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:29
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +371
   Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.ContentZone(Object Display, Object Shape, TextWriter Output) in c:\Project\Web\Intranet.NET\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:286
```

Comment: If you respect the convention, yes. Please provide a link to the doc you are referring to.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Please see the edit of my question, i've added the docs link.

Comment: Rename the original Orchard.Core/Containers/Views/Parts.Container.Contained.cshtml shape and see what the error message tells you where it tries to find the Foo_Bar shape

Comment: @devqon See the edit of my question, i get an exception.